# Mutual SSL authentication with PHP SOAP

Tags: php, ssl, soap, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to get mutual ssl authentication working between two LAMP servers.

I actually have 3 servers. One being the master and the other two are clients making SOAP calls to it.

On the master and one client I have Comodo Postive SSL certificates installed. I can connect from that client to the master and have the SSL authentication succeed.

On the second client I installed a Lets Encrypt certificate. I got the root certificate from their website (and also verified it was correct using https://whatsmychaincert.com).

This server fails the soap call. I've checked the httpd error log on the master and it has this:

```
SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!]
```

My understanding is that this means that the CLIENT is not verifying the MASTER's certificate.

If I use cURL from the command line on this client that does work. I call cURL like this:

```
curl  -v --cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/ssl3.demoserver.co.za/cert.pem
  --cacert /etc/letsencrypt/live/ssl3.demoserver.co.za/combined.crt 
  --key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ssl3.demoserver.co.za/privkey.pem
      https://ssl2.demoserver.co.za/index.php
```

In this case combined.crt is a file with both the comodo chain and the letsencrypt chain concatenated.

The PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php

$contextOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer'   => true,
    'cafile'        => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/ssl3.demoserver.co.za/combined.crt',
    'local_cert'        => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/ssl3.demoserver.co.za/keycert.pem',
    'verify_depth'  => 5,
    'disable_compression' => true,
    'SNI_enabled'         => true
)
);

$sslContext = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

$options2 = array(
    'uri' => 'https://ssl2.demoserver.co.za',
            'location' => 'https://ssl2.demoserver.co.za/Soap.php',
            'trace' => 1,
            'stream_context' => $sslContext
    );

$client = new SoapClient(NULL, $options2);
print "<span style=\"color:green;\">'".$client->GetData()."'<span>";

?>
```

The keycert.pem file is a concatenation of the private key and the certificate.

All of the servers are Centos7 with php 5.4.16

Answer (score 2):

I figured this one out (and by I, I mean a chap by the name of Dino ciuffetti). I came across [this blog](http://dino.ciuffetti.info/2013/11/apache-httpd-as-2way-auth-ssl-proxy-balancer/) which helped me understand mutual authentication a little more but I still could not quite get things working.

I mailed the blog poster, Dino, and he was kind enough to help me get things working. When I tried setting up the third server with LetsEncrypt on it by myself things didn't work as expected.

I once again reached out to Dino and he spotted that the certificate's directory did not allow apache read access.. A simple mistake but I guess I had been staring at this problem for too many hours to see the obvious.

Also, in the end the soap was simplified to :

```
$options2 = array(
    'uri' => 'https://ssl2.demoserver.co.za',
            'location' => 'https://ssl2.demoserver.co.za/Soap.php',
            'trace' => 1,
            'local_cert' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/ssl3.demoserver.co.za/keycert.pem'
    );

$client = new SoapClient(NULL, $options2);
print "<span style=\"color:green;\">'".$client->GetData()."'<span>";
```